# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word - Overwriting text in current document, how to stop this?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to add text to a document and format it appropriately.

It works as long as there is no text after the insertion point, but if there is then it overwrites it. Why is that?

Here is my code in which the text is written. Again, this works if there is nothing after it.

```
// Header
var p = p2.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
var x = p.Range.Paragraphs.Count;
p.Range.Text = String.Format(headerText + "\r\n");
p.Range.set_Style("Req Level " + layerNumber.ToString() + " - Body");

// Description
p2 = p.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
p2.Range.Text = String.Format(bodyText + "\r\n");
p2.Range.set_Style("Req Level " + layerNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: Try : Application.Options.Overtype = false

Comment: Didn't work, good idea though. I couldn't find that earlier when I thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the description at the same level as header:

```
    var pp = p2.Range.Paragraphs.Add();
    pp.Range.Text = String.Format(bodyText + "\r\n");
    pp.Range.set_Style("Req Level " + layerNumber.ToString());
```

Comment: It's overwriting things that are currently in the document, not the headers and descriptions

Comment: To debug, don' update text and just change style to identify the modified range.

Comment: Instead of adding CRLF at text end, you may execute p.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();